# Chia seeds as replacement of oil in bakery

Tags: baking, substitutions, chia

I found that chia seeds mixed with water form a somewhat gelatin mixture that can be used for bakery instead of oil or butter.

I would like to try it but I have no idea if I should replace 1/3 cup of oil with a 1/3 cup of this mixture and what would the proportion of water/seeds be.

Can anyone give some pointers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Pure Goodness](http://www.puregoodness.net/health/superfoods-chia-seeds/):

> Chia gel can substitute for half the butter in most recipes! The food
>   will bake the same and taste the same (or better) from the addition of
>   the chia gel. All you need to do is divide the amount of butter or oil
>   in half, and then use the same amount of chia gel to fill in. [...] Everything from cookies to cakes to muffins, pancakes and
>   waffles can be made with chia gel as your butter replacement.

Other sites bracket this range, recommending 25% replacement of the butter or oil (some indicating that it is very hard to tell the difference at this ratio) to as much as 75% (but that is fairly unusual); 50% seems to be the most common recommendation.

My survey of sites shows that most recommend making Chia Gel with a 1:9 ratio of seeds to liquid (usually water).  The instructions at [Health Central](http://www.healthcentral.com/diabetes/c/1071/52328/cooking-chia-seeds/) are fairly typical:

> Put water in a sealable plastic container and slowly pour seed into
>   water while briskly mixing with a wire whisk. This process will avoid
>   any clumping of the seed. Wait a couple of minutes, whisk again and
>   let stand for 5 to 10 minutes. Whisk again before using or storing in
>   refrigerator (Gel will keep up to 2 weeks).